How to clean data from Postgres installed with Airflow?
I got installed with Docker Airflow 2.8.2.
With Airflow, Postgres is also installed.
File path to Postgres is /***/airflow/postgres.
I found that Postgres folder takes to much memory.
/*/airflow/postgres/base takes 24 Gb.

All files got names like 16442, 16451, 16451_fsm and etc.
I think I need clean this folder, but I can't just delete this files.
How to figure out, which files I don't need and how to delete then properly?

Please don't post the output of shell commands etc. as images. It breaks search engines and screen readers.

you cannot remove that folder (base) because you will lose your data. There are solutions to fix the size. Log into the postgresql, usually by psql and do a vacuum:
VACUUM FULL;

depending on the size, it may take time.
For the logs also, you can use some cleanups like this one.

Nope. This not working in my case.
